# What is SELF JOIN and when would you use it?

Tags: sql, self-join

What is self join and when would you use it? I don't understand self joins so a layman explanation with an example would be great.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You use a self join when a table references data in itself.

E.g., an `Employee` table may have a `SupervisorID` column that points to the employee that is the boss of the current employee.

To query the data and get information for both people in one row, you could self join like this:

```
select e1.EmployeeID, 
    e1.FirstName, 
    e1.LastName,
    e1.SupervisorID, 
    e2.FirstName as SupervisorFirstName, 
    e2.LastName as SupervisorLastName
from Employee e1
left outer join Employee e2 on e1.SupervisorID = e2.EmployeeID
```

Comment: That looks like a self outer join to me?

Comment: @JoeCaruso That's because it is ;)

Comment: I wonder why noone emphasizes the "in the same row" part. Isn't that whole point of doing a self join?

Comment: don't we need `AS` when creating alias for tables?

Comment: @ManuChadha `AS` is optional - I will decide based on the readability of the query.

Comment: @JoeCaruso LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same thing

Answer (score 84):

Well, one classic example is where you wanted to get a list of employees and their immediate managers:

```
select e.employee as employee, b.employee as boss
from emptable e, emptable b
where e.manager_id = b.empolyee_id
order by 1
```

It's basically used where there is any relationship between rows stored in the same table.

- employees.
- multi-level marketing.
- machine parts.

And so on...

Answer (score 27):

A self join is simply when you join a table with itself. There is no `SELF JOIN` keyword, you just write an ordinary join where both tables involved in the join are the same table. One thing to notice is that when you are self joining it is necessary to use an alias for the table otherwise the table name would be ambiguous.

It is useful when you want to correlate pairs of rows from the same table, for example a parent - child relationship. The following query returns the names of all immediate subcategories of the category 'Kitchen'.

```
SELECT T2.name
FROM category T1
JOIN category T2
ON T2.parent = T1.id
WHERE T1.name = 'Kitchen'
```

Comment: Nice to see this comment..
ON T2.parent = T1.id (because it affects result if we interchange 'parent' and 'id' in it)

Comment: Good to mention there is no `SELF JOIN` keyword. I was confused about that part!

Answer (score 12):

SQL self-join simply is a normal join which is used to join a table to itself.

Example:

```
Select *
FROM Table t1, Table t2
WHERE t1.Id = t2.ID
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use `SELECT t1.*` in order to avoid duplicate column names in the result?

Answer (score 6):

You'd use a self-join on a table that "refers" to itself - e.g. a table of employees where managerid is a foreign-key to employeeid on that same table.

Example:

```
SELECT E.name, ME.name AS manager
FROM dbo.Employees E
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employees ME
ON ME.employeeid = E.managerid
```

Comment: ON ME.employeeid = E.managerid will create different result instead of ON ME.managerid = E.employeeid