# Find duplicate records in two group of data in one sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one sql server (2008) table containing group of data.

```
Source    PersonId    Date      Description   Code     IsDup
------    --------    -----     -----------   ------   ----- 
EHR       1234        1/1/2012  Fever         120.12
EHR       1234        6/1/2012  Fracture      101.00
EHR       1234        11/4/2012 Hypertension  223.15
RAM       1234        1/1/2012  Fever         120.12              <-- Duplicate
RAM       1234        6/1/2012  Fracture      101.00              <-- Duplicate
RAM       1234        4/1/2012  Diabetic      601.00
TAR       1234        2/1/2012  Asthma        456.00
TAR       1234        1/1/2012  Fever         120.12              <-- Duplicate
```

I need to compare the data between the different groups. "EHR" being the master group, I need to check if any other group has data exactly matching that in "EHR" master group within the table. And then it should update the IsDup column with 1.

**Expected Result:**

```
Source    PersonId    Date      Description   Code     IsDup
------    --------    -----     -----------   ------   ----- 
EHR       1234        1/1/2012  Fever         120.12
EHR       1234        6/1/2012  Fracture      101.00
EHR       1234        11/4/2012 Hypertension  223.15
RAM       1234        1/1/2012  Fever         120.12     1
RAM       1234        6/1/2012  Fracture      101.00     1
RAM       1234        4/1/2012  Diabetic      601.00
TAR       1234        2/1/2012  Asthma        456.00
TAR       1234        1/1/2012  Fever         120.12     1
```

I know how to check for duplicates within the table but not sure how can we do comparison keeping one group static.

I got this from one of the stackoverflow thread to identify dups but how to add grouped comparision:

```
with x as   (select  *, rn = row_number()
            over(PARTITION BY [PersonId], [Date], [Description], [Code] order by [PersonId], [Date], [Description], [Code])
            from    Results)

select * from x
where rn > 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your table using self join :

```
update r1 set isDup = 1
from results r1 join results r2 on 
     r1.PersonId = r2.PersonId and r1.Date = r2.Date and 
     r1.Description = r2.Description and r1.Code = r2.Code 
where r1.Source <> 'EHR' and r2.Source = 'EHR'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected. Lamak's solution was great too but we prefer self joins over exists.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
UPDATE A
SET IsDup = 1 
FROM YourTable A
WHERE [Source] != 'EHR'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
            WHERE [Source] = 'EHR'
            AND PersonId = A.PersonId 
            AND [Date] = A.[Date]
            AND Description = A.Description
            AND Code = A.Code)
```

[Here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0f1f/4) for you to try.

Comment: Thanks Lamak for your solution and the demo. I didn't know that there is a sqlfiddle too. Thanks for educating me. In past we had issues with EXISTS so our DBA prefer self join.

Comment: @kuul13 yeah, sqlfiddle is a great tool. Well, I don't know what "issues" your DBA had with `EXISTS` in the past, but I think that it was probably a misunderstanding on how it works. Just to keep with the "educating" part, I suggest you (and your DBA) take a look at this blog post: http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;With rootQuery as 
(
Select  SOURCE, PersonId, Date, Description, Code
From    MedicalHistory 
Where   Source = 'EHR'
)
Update mhd
Set IsDuplicate = 1
From    rootquery mh 
Join    MedicalHistory mhd on mh.PersonId = mhd.PersonId
Where   mh.Description = mhd.Description
And     mh.Code = mhd.Code
And         mh.Date = mhd.Date
And     mhd.Source != 'EHR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please..

```
   update tab
   set tab1.isDup=1
   from table1 tab1, table1 tab2
   where 
   tab1.PersonId=tab1.PersonId and
   tab1.Date=tab2.Date and
   tab1.desription=tab2.desription and
   tab1.Code=tab2.Code and
   tab1.Source != tab2.source
```