# Why is a row missing?

Tags: sql, hierarchy

I have small hierarchy table.

```
        NR  ENAME       BOSS 
       | 1| Johnson   | NULL|
       | 2| Jackson   | 1   |
       | 3| Wright    | 1   |
       | 4| Carell    | 3   |
       | 5| Statham   | 3   |
       | 6| Lincoln   | 4   |
```

Now I'd like to see every Employee and their Boss.

```
SELECT Employee.ENAME Employee, BOSS.ENAME Boss
FROM Employee
JOIN Employee AS Boss ON Employee.BOSS=Boss.NR
```

By running this I get every employee except **Johnson**. 
What do I need to do to get a row with Employee Johnson and Boss NULL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is SELF JOIN and when would you use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it)

Comment: Always a great reference http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `SELF JOIN` on your table and your BOSS column has `NULL` value against Johnson. You need to do it like this:-

```
SELECT Employee.ENAME Employee, BOSS.ENAME Boss
FROM Employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee AS Boss ON Employee.BOSS=Boss.NR
```