# price difference based on week dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the input like:

```
+-----+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| key | company | price | week_start | price_diff |
+-----+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| 123 | xxx     |    15 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 456 | xxx     |    20 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 789 | yyy     |    30 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 122 | zzz     |    40 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 123 | xxx     |    50 | 09-06-2015 |            |
| 456 | xxx     |    60 | 09-06-2015 |            |
| 333 | yyy     |    70 | 09-06-2015 |            |
+-----+---------+-------+------------+------------+
```

expected output:

update the column price_diff

```
+-----+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| key | company | price | week_start | price_diff |
+-----+---------+-------+------------+------------+
| 123 | xxx     |    15 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 456 | xxx     |    20 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 789 | yyy     |    30 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 122 | zzz     |    40 | 02-06-2015 |            |
| 123 | xxx     |    50 | 09-06-2015 |         35 |
| 456 | xxx     |    60 | 09-06-2015 |         40 |
| 333 | yyy     |    70 | 09-06-2015 |            |
+-----+---------+-------+------------+------------+
```

for `company= 'xxx'` and `key = 123` I want to take the price difference based on `week_start`. From the above input for `company = 'xxx'` and `key = 123`, second week has `price = 50` and the first week price = 15. I need to update the price_diff with difference of those two values.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What about `y`? There are only 2 weeks? Are they always like 02---09---16... or there can be 02---04---07---10---16...?

Comment: Thanks for Reply.. i have many weeks it will be always like 02---09---16 .. and i want to update the price_diff week to week and its only for company = 'xxx'

Answer (score 0):

The way you should proceed is to do a [self-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it), meaning joining the table with itself based on the 1 week difference between dates of the same company and the ID's of the company.

In my below query I have also added a JOIN on `KEY`s since this logic would apparently map your data, but I don't recommend using duplicate KEY values, if this the column which should contain unique values (in case you're not using a composite key).

But anyway, here is what you can try (assuming that your table is called `"prices"`):

```
SELECT p1.*
    , p1.price - p2.price AS 'price_diff'
FROM prices p1
    LEFT JOIN prices p2 ON p1.company = p2.company
        AND p2.week_start = p1.week_start - 7 * INTERVAL '1 day'
        AND p1.KEY = p2.KEY
ORDER BY p1.week_start, p1.company, p1.KEY
```

Also, a sample working [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ae229/5).

**Update:**

In order to update the `price_diff` column, based on my above query you will have to change it to an `UPDATE`, like below:

```
UPDATE prices
    SET price_diff = p1.price - p2.price
FROM prices p1
    LEFT JOIN prices p2 ON p1.company = p2.company
        AND p2.week_start = p1.week_start - 7 * INTERVAL '1 day'
        AND p1.KEY = p2.KEY
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I want to update the price_diff column

Comment: I got an error while while updating  Error:Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate.. I'm using Postgres

Comment: @kr_kr Are you using Amazon Redshift?

Comment: Yes I'm using Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a window function:

```
WITH diff (key, company, week_start, price) AS (
  SELECT key, company, week_start,
         price - lag(price) OVER (PARTITION BY key, company ORDER BY week_start)
  FROM mytable)
UPDATE mytable
SET price_diff = diff.price
FROM diff
WHERE company = 'xxx' AND diff.company = 'xxx'
  AND key = 123 AND diff.key = 123
  AND week_start = diff.week_start;
```

Comment: Your query gives me a syntax error. You have an extra apostrophe before `diff.key = 123`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update mytable
set price_diff = price - (
    select price
    from mytable as t2
    where 
        and t2.key = k1.key and t2.company = 'xxx'
        and t2.week_start = mytable.week_start - 7 * INTERVAL '1 day'
    )
where company = 'xxx' and price_diff is null
```