# How to efficiently SELECT a column's field based on another row with the same `id`?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
 id | title    | lang
----+----------+------
 1  | Moscow   | en
 1  | Москва   | ru
 2  | Helsinki | en 
 2  | Хельсинки| ru
```

I would like to efficiently get the `ru` title by `en` title.

At the moment, I get the `id` of the entry first and then make another query by hand.

Any other, more elegant, solutions?

Comment: Does not clear your question actually what you want, `english title?`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you please show us what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`SELF JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it) might be of help and is usually a preferable solution to lots of nested queries, if not for performance reasons (see: [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577224/3881403), [Rewriting Subqueries as Joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/rewriting-subqueries.html)) certainly for readability.

In your case try:

```
SELECT movies_ru.title 
 FROM movies AS movies_ru 
 JOIN movies AS movies_en 
 ON movies_ru.id = movies_en.id
 WHERE movies_ru.lang = "ru"
 AND movies_en.lang = "en"
 AND movies_en.title = "The English Title"
```

Comment: After reading "Join vs sub-query" I have to agree... @DainiusVaičiulis , are you hearing us?

Comment: @Siguza *nota bene*: I seem to understand that this is not an universal rule; according to benchmarks found on some Internet outlets, under Oracle, for example, there *seems* to be little or no penalty for nested `SELECT`s over self `JOIN`s. However, I think it's safe to take the MySQL reference manual at face value when it says *"A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better"*

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** It turns out [Tobia Tesan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31648626/2302862) is usually better practice.

---

Use a [subselect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT `title` FROM `table` WHERE `lang` = 'ru' AND `id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `lang` = 'en' AND `title` = 'Moscow')
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this whit this simple query:-

```
SELECT title FROM table 
WHERE lang = 'ru'
 AND
 id = (SELECT id FROM table WHERE lang = 'en' AND title = 'Moscow')
```

Comment: Except `table` is a keyword, and needs to be escaped, or you'll hit a syntax error.