# Aggregating multiple rows more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I've got a set of data which has an `type` column, and a `created_at` time column. I've already got a query which is pulling the relevant data from the database, and this is the data that is returned.

```
type            | created_at                   | row_num
-----------------------------------------------------
"ordersPage"    | "2015-07-21 11:32:40.568+12" | 1
"getQuote"      | "2015-07-21 15:49:47.072+12" | 2
"completeBrief" | "2015-07-23 01:00:15.341+12" | 3
"sendBrief"     | "2015-07-24 08:59:42.41+12"  | 4
"sendQuote"     | "2015-07-24 18:43:15.967+12" | 5
"acceptQuote"   | "2015-08-03 04:40:20.573+12" | 6
```

The row number is returned from the standard row number function in postgres

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS row_num
```

What I want to do is somehow aggregate this data so get a time distance between every event, so the output data might look something like this

```
type_1          | type_2          | time_distance
--------------------------------------------------------
"ordersPage"    | "getQuote"      | 123423.3423
"getQuote"      | "completeBrief" | 123423.3423
"completeBrief" | "sendBrief"     | 123423.3423
"sendBrief"     | "sendQuote"     | 123423.3423
"sendQuote"     | "acceptQuote"   | 123423.3423
```

The time distance would be a float in milliseconds, in other queries I've been using something like this to get time differences.

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (MAX(events.created_at) - MIN(events.created_at)))
```

But this time i need it for every pair of events in the sequential order of the row_num so I need the aggregate for `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)...`

Any ideas if this is possible? Also doesn't have to be exact, I can deal with duplicates, and with `type_1` and `type_2` columns returning an existing row in a different order. I just need a way to at least get those values above.

Comment: `JOIN` the data returned to itself on `t1.row_num=t2.row_num+1` to get  every pair of events in the sequential order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it) ? It would look like this :

```
SELECT 
  t1.type
  , t2.type
  , ABS(t1.created_at - t2.created_at) AS time_diff
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN your_table t2
ON t1.row_num = t2.row_num + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select type_1,
       type_2,
       created_at_2-created_at_1 as time_distance
from
(select 
type type_1,
lead(type,1) over (order by row_num) type_2,
created_at created_at_1,
lead(created_at,1) over (order by row_num) created_at_2
from table_name) temp
where type_2 is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LAG window function to compare the current value with the previous:

```
with
  t(type,created_at) as (
    values
      ('ordersPage', '2015-07-21 11:32:40.568+12'::timestamptz),
      ('getQuote', '2015-07-21 15:49:47.072+12'),
      ('completeBrief', '2015-07-23 01:00:15.341+12'),
      ('sendBrief', '2015-07-24 08:59:42.41+12'),
      ('sendQuote', '2015-07-24 18:43:15.967+12'),
      ('acceptQuote', '2015-08-03 04:40:20.573+12'))

select *, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM created_at - lag(created_at) over (order by created_at))
from t
order by created_at
```