# I need to make a table in mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin

I need help in how to make a table in MYSQL from this picture: The picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQMlE.jpg)

I made the normal table but i don't know how to make the ISA connection from angajat to manager knowing that the manager is from the the table column functie

Comment: Can you please include a clear picture

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Self join to make this ISA 
Connection
You can refer : [What is SELF JOIN and when would you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it)