# How can I find the parent table of a foreign constraint key in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

How can I find the parent table(s) of foreign constraint(s) on a table key in oracle?  I'm needing to create a dropdown of all of the values that can be selected for this column I'm looking at and need to know the parent so I can look up its sibling values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query this information from [`all_constraints`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1037.htm#i1576022) (or `user_constraints` or `dba_constraints`, of course). Unfortunately, you can only retrieve the name of the **constraint** a foreign key refers to, so you'll have to use a sub query or a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it) to retrieve the referring table:

```
SELECT r.table_name
FROM   user_constraints t
JOIN   user_constraints r ON t.r_constraint_name = r.constraint_name
WHERE  t.constraint_type = 'R' AND t.table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
```

Comment: So I should apply this to the table that has the constraint?  The child table?

Comment: @Dale yup - replace `'SOME_TABLE'` with the name of the table that has the foreign key constraints (the child table) and you should get the name[s] of the table[s] it references (the parent table[s])

Comment: I did this and received an error of ORA-00904: "R"."CONSTRAINTS_NAME": invalid identifier

Comment: @Dale That was a typo, mea culpa. It's supposed to be "constraint_name". I've edited the answer and fixed it.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get the parent table.

```
select * from all_constraints
where constraint_name in (select r_constraint_name from all_constraints
where table_name in 'TAB_NAME');
```