# small tricky query on self join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table EMP with columns as below:

```
create table emp(
empno    number(4,0),
ename    varchar2(10),
job      varchar2(9),
mgr_id   number(4,0),
sal      number(7,2),
deptno   number(2,0));
```

I want to list all employees' names along with their manager names, including those who do not have a manager. For those employees, their manager's name should be displayed as 'BOSS'.

Comment: PL/SQL is associated with Oracle.  I changed the tags accordingly.  There is nothing tricky about this question at all.  You should learn SQL so you can answer such questions.

Comment: if you know the answer please let me know

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
select e.ename, (case when m.ename is null then 'BOSS' else m.ename end) as mgrName 
from emp e
left join emp m on m.empno = e.mgr_id
```

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, the better solution is proposed by Charanjith.

In Oracle, we could even use NVL function instead of "case when" in order to replace null value by something. The result should be the same.

```
select e.ename empName, NVL(m.ename, 'BOSS') mgrName from emp e
left join emp m on m.empno = e.mgr_id
```

Moreover, we could see another solution : using inner join to filter on emp when a manager exists. Then union for all employees who don't have any manager.

```
select e.ename empName, m.ename mgrName from emp e inner join emp m on e.mgr_id = m.empno
union
select e.ename empName, 'BOSS' mgrName from emp e where not exists (select 1 from emp m where e.mgr_id = m.empno)
```

Comment: we can get by using like this  decode (m.ename, null, 'BOSS', m.ename);

Comment: Best case would be using `COALESCE` instead of `CASE`/`NVL`, which is Standard SQL and a shortcut for a CASE.

Answer (score 0):

This work fine in oracle:

```
SELECT e.ename,
 nvl(m.ename, 'BOSS')mgr
   FROM emp a
LEFT JOIN emp b
ON m.empno = e.mgr_id;
```