# How can I combine 2 rows into 1 with sqlite-android

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I combine 2 rows into 1 with sqlite-android.

There are 2 rows in my sqlite table.

Basically, parent does not have any 'null' value.
However, child may have 'null'.

child's 'null' will be changed to parent's 'non-null' value.

```
(example)
title     item1     item2     item3
------------------------------------
parent    1         2         3
child     null      20        null
```

If I combine above 2 rows,

```
(combine above table)
title     item1     item2     item3
------------------------------------
child     1         20        3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to check before inserting if your child value is null, insert your parent value

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the data, or to modify the table?

Comment: @CL. I wanna get combined cursor from original table

Answer (score 0):

To combine two rows into one output row, use a [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it); to replace NULL values, use [ifnull()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
SELECT c.title,
       ifnull(c.item1, p.item1),
       ifnull(c.item2, p.item2),
       ifnull(c.item3, p.item3)
FROM MyTable AS p
JOIN MyTable AS c ON p.title = 'parent'
                 AND c.title = 'child';
```