# how to display elements based on key value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have the following table `$region_data = DB::table('region_mapping')->get();`

```
$region_data = DB::table('region_mapping')->groupBy('region_id')->get();
```

[image: Without Groupby]

[image: With group By]

On using groupby it is not displaying all the fields in region center what can i do for this. if there is modification please tell me comment section.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need a self join here

Comment: can u please explain it @madalinivascu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it

Comment: it is not helping me is there any other method @madalinivascu