# Search duplicated values and show their context

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm not sure if the solution for this question is incredible simple or not possible in pure SQL.

---

I have a simple table with 2 columns

```
Number    Text
1         a
1         b
2         m
3         x
3         y
3         z
```

Now the task is:
Search all repeated numbers and show the "Text" which uses these duplicated numbers.

We see: 1 is used twice (with a and b), 3 is used with x and y and z. But no line is completely duplicated.

Edit:
So I expect something like this.

```
   Dup_Num    Text
    1         a
    1         b
    3         x
    3         y
    3         z
```

The search for the duplicate is easy, but I don't have an idea how to connect is with "Text", because when I add "Text" to my SELECT I have to use it for GROUP and this give no duplicates ..

Thanks for help on a lousy day ..

Comment: With the sample data above, what are your expected results? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Just use `listagg(text, ',') within group(order by text) `

Comment: (Sorry, I'm to simple to understand the formatting here in the comments): 
I expect a grid like this:

dup_nums    Text
1         a
1         b
3         x
3         y
3         z

Or maybe in another form like
dup_nums    all_texts
1                 a, b
3                 x,y,z

Comment: @PierredelaVerre . . . You should edit the *question* not add a comment.  What the results look like is a critical part of the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yes, you are right. I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.number = t.number and t2.text <> t.text)
order by t.number;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(number, text)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that's a fine solution too.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to find duplicates in SQL is the [self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362038/what-is-self-join-and-when-would-you-use-it).

In your [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gqr4GmbHe3q6HMWx3J3zDM/0):

```
select s1.*
from stuff s1
inner join stuff s2
  on s1.number = s2.number
  and s1.text <> s2.text
```

Comment: Thanks Neville; I modified it a little bit to "SELECT DISTINCT S1.*..." and get exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @PierredelaVerre . . . `SELECT DISTINCT` significantly slows down the query.  The `EXISTS` solution should have better performance.

Comment: Gordon's solution is probably the faster one. It usually is.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I changed now the "correct solution"

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might want to use LISTAGG to group those values and its relation to the other column

```
SQL> with result 
as (
select '1' as c1 , 'a' as c2 from dual union all
select '1' as c1 , 'b' as c2 from dual union all
select '2' as c1 , 'm' as c2 from dual union all
select '3' as c1 , 'x' as c2 from dual union all
select '3' as c1 , 'y' as c2 from dual union all
select '3' as c1 , 'z' as c2 from dual )
select c1, listagg(c2,',') within group(order by c1) as c3 from result
group by c1;

C C3
- --------------------
1 a,b
2 m
3 x,y,z

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto; this solution would be a part of the second option. The poster below showed me the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might also help you.

```
 select * from t where Number in 
 (select Number from t group by Number having count(*) > 1)
 order by Text
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mnVZ3jrvTeim5kdvZuThp5/1)